# Redirecting Issue - Site only redirecting on mobile but not on Desktop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have this site on WordPress  http://vergelabogados.pe/ and I make a  redirect in the index.php to another site
But nothing happens on desktop, but in a mobile device works fine. I try to find out code on .htaccess file, index file, but I can't find  nothing. I Google it but not found any helpful solution. Any suggestion what could be the reason for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your .htaccess file :
Permanently redirect all request to yourdomain.com/index.php to another site : `Redirect 301 index.php http://another.site/`
Permanently redirect all request to yourdomain.com (Root domain) to another site : `Redirect 301 index.php http://another.site/`

More info : https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file

Answer (score 0):

// This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain

**Redirect 301 / http://max2colors.com/**
use this in htaccess file

visit this http://max2colors.com